# Instagram closed api for POST and DELETE methods.

Tags: api, post, scope, instagram, relationships

So as of now Instagram changed the policy and now i can't create an access token with relationships+likes scope. But third party apps like Crowdfire still work. On official Instagram page they said that only third party apps that will receive the privilege of advanced scope are the apps that Instagram itself approved. Anyone had any experience filing the application for approval? Or can you guys give me tips of how to bypass that.

p.s.
I have an app that creates multiple access_tokens for different client, nothing spammy, just likes the feed of users and automatically follows people that followed them. (yeah, some people are into that) And mass unfollow (idk if thats bad or not)